# Rails 4 get remote ip address of client getting error "::1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ip

I have been wondering about getting ip of client, I always get value `"::1"`.
I do this to get my local ip address

```
request.remote_ip
```

I have another rails application by doing that it works well with `127.0.0.1` as a result. Do you have suggestion for this. I would appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the apps using the same server?

Comment: Yes, It is. I use development environment in my local machine but I never try in production.

Answer (score 1):

::1 is the actual IP. It is an ipv6 loopback address (i.e. localhost). If you were using ipv4 it would be 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I hope so. But why did my another rails 4 apps show me `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Did that happen on the same development machine on the same day? Are you using virtualization per app (IE docker)? This is dependent on the machine setup: if it's using IP4 vs IP6.

Comment: Yes, It did. I have two apps in my machine. I have tried in same day.